# I cant seed data in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, seeding

H have 2 tables, users and authors and I have their respective models. But when I try to seed the following error occurs:

> Class 'Author' not found in
>   /var/www/html/shopping/database/seeds/AuthorsTableSeeder.php on line
>   12
>
> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]     Class
>   'Author' not found

Earlier I had the same problem with my users table but I fixed it by adding `use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User;`

Here is my authors seeder.php

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


Class AuthorsTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {
DB::table('authors')->delete();

        Author::create(array(
            'name' => 'Lauren',
            'surname'=>'Oliver'
        ));

        Author::create(array(
            'name' => 'Stephenie',
            'surname'=>'Meyer'
        ));

        Author::create(array(
            'name' => 'Dan',
            'surname'=>'Brown'
        ));

    }

}
```

and my databaseseeder.php is below

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;


class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
    Eloquent::unguard();

    $this->call('UsersTableSeeder');
    $this->command->info('Users table seeded!');
    $this->call('AuthorsTableSeeder');
    $this->command->info('Authors table seeded!');

    }
}
```

Also here is my [website folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIQwI.png) as well.

Comment: Maybe show us a screenshot of your file directory. That will be quite helpful in diagnosing your issue, instead of us guessing what the file name could be.

Comment: Can we see the code in your Author.php file?

Comment: Yep, what's the class named in your Author.php file ?

Comment: ok..i will upload it

Comment: jed i have only the following code in author.php     <?php
Class Author extends Eloquent {

protected $table = 'authors';

protected $fillable = array('name','surname');

}

Comment: namespace App;   should be at the top, under <?php

Comment: no brother..its still showing class author not found

Comment: Look at my updated answer. You need to add `namespace App` in the Authors.php file. Then you can add, `use App\Authors` in your seeder file.

Comment: If all else fails, try running, on the command line, in the project directory: composer dump-autoload

Comment: now its showing  Class 'App\Eloquent' not found

Comment: Boom!  We're getting closer.

Comment: [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]  
  Class 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent' not found

Comment: Or:  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;    I'm not sure, what version of Laravel are you using?!

Comment: [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]  
  Class 'App\Eloquent' not found

Comment: Try changing "Class Author extends Eloquent" to "Class Author extends Model"

Comment: It would help to know if you were using 5.x or 4.x, because the differences are significant.

Comment: not working [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]  
  Class 'App\Model' not found

Comment: am using laravel 5

Comment: try deleting the file and recreating it?   php artisan make:model Author

Comment: can you tell me how this statement works "use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User;"

Comment: In what context?  It just means, make that class available...

Comment: i have two models users.php and author.php . i couldnt seed users table using App/User, but the i used this "use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User;" in user.php model and it worked.. can i use something like this to author.php so that it also works

Comment: The class we're trying to find here is "App\Author".  So, "use App\Author". 
User is based off of Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User, so that's my only guess on how that is working.  Something is preventing Laravel from finding your models.

Comment: Did you try recreating the file with "php artisan make:model Author"? Did you try running "composer dump-autoload"?

Comment: yes..still not working

Comment: Which laravel version are you use ?

Comment: I'm at a loss...  Try the following.

Comment: composer update

Comment: php artisan cache:clear

Comment: php artisan clear-compiled

Comment: i will try that... anyways thanks for your support mate

Comment: got the answer.. i have posted it in the answer section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found the answer. the problem was with the syntax. i used the following and it worked

```
<?php namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

Class Author extends Model {

protected $fillable = array('name','surname');
protected $table = 'authors';



}
```

i replaced the positions of the following code
    protected $fillable = array('name','surname');
        protected $table = 'authors';

and i used 'model' instead of 'eloquent' and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Add model name `Author` at  `AuthorsTableSeeder`.

```
use App\Author;
```

Since, you are using Author model with out adding at the top.

Comment: i used it.. but its showing Class 'App\Author' not found

Comment: I have thought Author is your model ? What is Author ? Model or something else ?

Comment: He'll just need to specify where the actual model is located. Maybe he put it in a _model_ / _models_ folder.

Comment: @giollianosulit Yes, I've thought model is at Laravel `App/` folder

Comment: Author is my model.. i dnt have a models folder. my models are under app folder

Comment: @ZubairNazerOliyat Then above should work. I wonder what's wrong with your seeder.

Comment: Is it named **Authors** ?

Comment: @ZubairNazerOliyat Why are you deleting table in seeder ? can you explain ?

Comment: the model  name author.php

Comment: sagar gautam.. actually i am new to laravel.. i am doing this looking at a pdf.  is it not cecesary to use delete?

Comment: @ZubairNazerOliyat It's totally unnecessary.

Comment: sagar gautam.. isn't it necessary to use that delete so that once we update the table no duplicate value is added

Comment: Table delete will remove whole table structure so it's unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


Class AuthorsTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('authors')->delete();

        DB::table('authors')->insert(array(
            'name' => 'Lauren',
            'surname'=>'Oliver'
        ));

        DB::table('authors')->insert(array(
            'name' => 'Stephenie',
            'surname'=>'Meyer'
        ));

        DB::table('authors')->insert(array(
            'name' => 'Dan',
            'surname'=>'Brown'
        ));

    }

}
```

Hope this work for you !!!

Comment: as am new to stackoverflow and i haven't got much reputation they wont show my vote

Comment: @ZubairNazerOliyat : Please follow this link(https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow) for upvote

Comment: @ZubairNazerOliyat : Please follow this link(https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for accept answer.